# My computer cannot access website running on it while other computers can

Tags: apache

I am building a website with Apache and PHP. I was able to run it on my computer till yesterday.Now, I cannot access it on my own computer with localhost,127.0.0.1 but other computers on my network can access it using my ip. I was trying to install some software yesterday which made Chrome totally dysfunctional and I had to reinstall it. Chrome/IE can access other websites but not my own.

Anybody has any idea about this?

Comment: Check apache binding in config file or check if 1) apache binding to localhost?  check `telnet localhost 80` 2) binding to network ip?  `telnet <network ip> 80` 3) does it really bind to 0.0.0.0 (all ports)?  both #1 and #2.  the telnet tests if apache listened on the addresses at port 80. In the telnets, type in `GET /index.html HTTP/1.1`  If you get responses, then the issue might be your browser.  If so, I'd check to see if the software install messed with your proxy settings.  Maybe you can open a web console in a browser to look at the requests and see where the connections get servered.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Yes, my telnet connection to localhost or to my IP address is not working. How I should fix this now???

Comment: I also noticed an interesting thing. I installed that malicious software yesterday. My host file was also edited at the same time. I can see few websites listed in hosts file. Now, when I try to edit hosts file and save it. After some time it edits itself back and show last edited on 01/21/2016.

Comment: I would say it is probably that particular software causing the issue. I would run the malwarebytes virus scan (maybe in safe mode) to clean it out before proceeding.  If you have a full system backup from before the issue, I would consider rolling the whole system back.

Comment: Thanks, I scanned it and it is working properly now.